# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current'

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

```
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print self,self.parent.current

class AppScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

#Base Class
class AppBaseClass(App):
    def build(self):
        icon='app_icon'
        return Builder.load_file('appbase.kv')


________________________________________________________________________________________________

AppScreenManager:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    LoginScreen:
```

Error:  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current'. Please help.

Comment: where does this error ocurr? I don't see `current` being called

Comment: @LawrenceBenson Please check now.

Comment: And where is `self.parent` being assigned?

Comment: @DanielRoseman In the kivy I am guessing, it apparently does work in the same app at later time.

Comment: Can't figure the reason for downvotes!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you call:

```
print self,self.parent.current
```

the LoginScreen is not instantiated yet, so you are calling for and object that does not exist.

The workaround is to delay the call by 1 frame, that can be done using Clock class:

```
 Clock.schedule_once(self._myprintfunction, 1/60)
```

and latter in your code but in the same class:

```
    def _myprintfunction(self, dt):
        print '-'*25
        print self
        print self.parent
        # print self.parent.curet <- this will throw you an error 
        print '-'*25
```

Hope it helps.